# how do I either stop the tween at the point of my choice (first code)? or how do I stop the easing (second code)?

Tags: actionscript-3

*This is for `Actionscript 3.0` on `CS5`.
I've been having some issues with `fl.transitions.easing.None.easeNone.` I tried to animate my MovieClip character without easing and stopping on a dime. I used the following code to stop the easing:*

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);

function keyPressed(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
         if(evt.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT && var_move == false)
         {
    var_move = true;
    hero.gotoAndStop("Walk");
    hero.scaleX = 1;
    var tween1:Tween = new Tween(hero, "x", None.easeNone, hero.x, hero.x+75, 15, false)
    tween1.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onMotionFinished);
          }

       if(evt.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT && var_move == false)
       {
        var_move = true;
        hero.gotoAndPlay("Walk");
        hero.scaleX = -1;
    var tween2:Tween = new Tween(hero, "x", None.easeNone, hero.x, hero.x-75, 15, false)
    tween2.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onMotionFinished);
        }
}

function onMotionFinished($evt:TweenEvent):void
{
    hero.gotoAndPlay("Stand");
    var_move = false;

}
```

*Which it did but if you just tap Right or Left Arrow the MovieClip character will not stop on that frame. It continues until the tween is done. If I use the following code:*

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, releaseKey);

function keyPressed(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(evt.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
        var_move = true;
        hero.gotoAndPlay("Walk");
        hero.scaleX = 1;
        hero.x += 5;
    }

    if(evt.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
    {
        var_move = true;
        hero.gotoAndPlay("Walk");
        hero.scaleX = -1;
        hero.x -= 5;
    }
}

function releaseKey(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(evt.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT || evt.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
    {
        hero.gotoAndStop("Stand");
    }
}
```

*the MovieClip character eases into the walk animation, but stops where I want it to. how do I either stop the tween at the point of my choice (first code) or how do I stop the easing (second code)?*

Answer (score 2):

For tweening, I highly recommend using the library at http://greensock.com ... the free TweenMax/TweenLite will save you tons of time trying to solve problems like this... they already did the hard part :)